# Why can't I create a singly linked list from an array?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I need to make a singly-linked list for my array of integers, but, I don't know what is currently wrong with my code right now.

This is the code to create the nodes. (the data)

```
package sllset;

class SLLNode {
    int value;
    SLLNode next;

public SLLNode(int i, SLLNode n){
    value = i;
    next = n   
    }   
}
```

My other class which has my methods and constructors look like this.

```
package sllset;


public class SLLSet {
    private int setSize;
    private SLLNode head;

public SLLSet(){
    head = null;
    setSize = 0;
}

public SLLSet(int[] sortedArray){ //second constructor
    setSize = sortedArray.length;
    int i;
    head=null;
    for(i=0;i<setSize;i++){
        head.next = head;
        head = new SLLNode(sortedArray[i],head.next);    
    }
}


public String toString(){
    SLLNode p;
    String result = new String();
    for(p=head ; p!=null ; p=p.next)
        result += p.value;
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] A = {2,3,6,8,9};
SLLSet a = new SLLSet(A);
System.out.println(a.toString());

    }

}
```

My problem is that my second constructor doesn't work and I dont really have a clue as to why. I have been following a guide on how to make most of these functions so my knowledge of the code I guess isn't great enough to decipher the problem.

EDIT: So someone told me to specify the problem which I get a NULLPointerException at line 19; where I code head.next = head; . However, when 
I remove that part to test, line 20 gets the error message

Comment: It doesn't work? How do you know?

Comment: I've tried running it

Comment: @shmosel very funny

Comment: It gives me a nullpointerexception at line 19: so where I put head.next = head. When I take it out, line 20 gets an error.

Comment: Bingo! Please include that in the question.

Comment: This _isn't_ a duplicate of null pointer exception.  His constructor has a logical problem with it.

Comment: See the Wombat's answer for a fix for your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this

```
head=null;     // you are setting head to null
for(i=0;i<setSize;i++){
    head.next = head;  // see two lines up, head is null, it can not have next
```

Your constructor has some problems.  Try using this version:

```
public SLLSet(int[] sortedArray){ //second constructor
    head = null;
    if (sortedArray == null || sortedArray.length == 0) {
        setSize = 0;
    }
    setSize = sortedArray.length;
    head = new SLLNode(sortedArray[0], null);
    SLLNode curr = head;

    for (int i=1; i < setSize; ++i) {
        curr.next = new SLLNode(sortedArray[i], null);
        curr = curr.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the code mean that before the loop my head = null (nothing in the list yet besides null). Then when I start looping in integers the value null would be moved to the right? OHH  or does it mean that my next head (head means the beginning of the list right?) Im basically saying the next value is null again?

Comment: Yes, when you create each new node, the next value is by default `null`.  This is how linked lists work, it has to end somewhere.  Try the code and come back here with comments.

Comment: I tried the code that was given but there seems to be a error: uncomplilable source code - Erroneous sym type: sllset.SLLSet.SLLNode. at curr.next = SLLNode(sortedArray[i],null). EDIT: Nevermind, i fixed it by adding new in front of it. Seems to have fixed it

Comment: I think i fixed it by allocating memory for it.

Comment: `curr.next = new SLLNode(sortedArray[i],null);`

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer correct if it solved your problem, thanks.